# A word to mean "reinterpreted, re-stipulated and/or restated"

Tags: single-word-requests

> The Bible's Old Testament (OT) Sacrificial rituals/practices were "reinterpreted, re-stipulated and/or restated" in the Bible's New Testament (NT) account of Lord Jesus Christ's sacrificial death on the cross.

I'm trying to find a better word/phrase (preferable word as opposed to phrase) than "reinterpreted, re-stipulated and/or restated".

Could someone please suggest an appropriate word/phrase that can be a substitute?

> **Update:** The Bible's Old Testament (OT) Sacrificial rituals/practices transfigured, though with same objective, into the
> Bible's New Testament (NT) account of Lord Jesus Christ's sacrificial
> death on the cross.

Does the updated version seem more suitable?

Comment: "Reimagined" or "reframed" comes to mind as being appropriate for your context.

Comment: re-interpreted and re-stipulated mean very different things. Why would you want one word that covered both?

Comment: @djclayworth Yes, LOL, I was just taking like wild educated guesses.  I just something something that is as accurate as possible, but also relatively brief.

Comment: @RobJarvis I would also say that "restated" doesn't convey what the OP is trying to say since "restating" something essentially confirms the previous statement and leaves it unchanged.

Comment: To help avoid guessing, please [edit] your question to say what aspects of the term you’re seeking are missing from the words in the quote.